# Video call recording in Twilio Android SDK

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-api

I know Twilio doesn't support video call recording on server but I've been trying to figure out how to do it locally on the android end. I have studied the [video-quickstart-android](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android) code in my try to figure out how i can extract the video stream from the [LocalVideoTrack](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/conversations/releases/0.12.2/docs/com/twilio/conversations/LocalVideoTrack.html) and [VideoTrack](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/conversations/releases/0.12.2/docs/com/twilio/conversations/VideoTrack.html) classes of the Twilio android conversations API but couldn't find any such method from where i could extract the underlying Video Stream and record it locally on the android device.

Anyone have any idea how I can get video stream for recording the video locally on the android device from [Twilio conversations api for android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/conversations)?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to write a custom video renderer that takes each frame and converts them into your preferred media format.

As an example the `VideoViewRenderer` takes frames and passes them to the `org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer`, rendering them to a View. In this case you would write another renderer, perhaps named `VideoRecorderRenderer` that implemented the `VideoRenderer` interface and did the work of taking each `I420Frame` and converting to a media type. You could then add the `VideoRecorderRenderer` to the `VideoTrack`. However, this alone may not be the solution you are looking for since this is only the video portion of the media, and does not provide the audio. The `AudioTrack` does not expose an interface to capture the audio output at the moment.